# How to pass values from view to controller using jquery function in asp.net mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to pass values from view to controller, controller having action method that will call webmethod to set values into database. how can i do that?

- need not to create a view of using model.

I have a view that get the values from database and having one link that is comment. on click of comment one textarea box will open and after providing some input. will click on ok button.

on click of button ok i am calling

```
    $('a.comment').livequery("click", function (e) {
    var getpID = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace('commentBox-', '');
    var comment_text = $("#commentMark-" + getpID).val();
    //alert(getpID);
    //alert(comment_text);
    if (comment_text != "Write a comment...") {
        //$.post("/Home/SetComment?comment_text=" + comment_text + "&post_id-= " + getpID, {

    }, function (response) {

        $('#CommentPosted' + getpID).append($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
        //            $("#commentMark-" + getpID).val("Write a comment...");
        $("#commentMark-" + getpID).val();
    });
}
```

now what can i do to get getpId and comment_text values to the controllers SetComment action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method to send them as an AJAX request:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("SetComment", "Home")';
var data = { commentText: comment_text, postId: getpID };
$.post(url, data, function(result) {
    // TODO: do something with the response from the controller action
});
```

which will post to the following action:

```
public ActionResult SetComment(string commentText, string postId) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin Dimitrov! I have the same code for another action but its not working can you please help me out. please find my code -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344877/calling-action-from-javascript-function

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery post http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post("/Home/SetComment",{comment_text:Text,postId:PostId},function(data){

 });
```